# AVMutableVideoComposition stops video from rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation

I am trying to get a composition of 2 videos playing simultaneously in different positions based on this tutorial: https://abdulazeem.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/video-manipulation-in-ios-resizingmerging-and-overlapping-videos-in-ios/

Here is my code:

```
-(AVPlayer*)create{

// assets
AVAsset* videoAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video_mov" ofType:@"mov"]]];
AVAsset* videoAsset2 = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video_mov" ofType:@"mov"]]];

// create a mutable composition and 2 tracks
AVMutableComposition* mutableComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack* videoTrack1 = [mutableComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVMutableCompositionTrack* videoTrack2 = [mutableComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

// add tracks from the video asset into the videoTrack1 (MutableCompositionTrack)
[videoTrack1 insertTimeRange: CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
                     ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                      atTime:kCMTimeZero
                       error:nil];

[videoTrack2 insertTimeRange: CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset2.duration)
                     ofTrack:[[videoAsset2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                      atTime:kCMTimeZero
                       error:nil];

// Add audio tracks from the audio asset to our audioCompositionTrack
[audioCompositionTrack insertTimeRange: CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration)
                               ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]
                                atTime:kCMTimeZero
                                 error:nil];

// Now create composition instructions for
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
MainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration);

// Track 1
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* FirstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack1];
CGAffineTransform Scale = videoTrack1.preferredTransform;
CGAffineTransform Move = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(300,200);
[FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(Scale,Move) atTime:kCMTimeZero];

// Track 2
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *SecondlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack2];
CGAffineTransform SecondScale = videoTrack1.preferredTransform;
CGAffineTransform SecondMove = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
[SecondlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(SecondScale,SecondMove) atTime:kCMTimeZero];

//Now we add our 2 created AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction objects to our AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction in form of an array.
MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstlayerInstruction,nil];

// now create a video composition with the instruction, and set our instructions
AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
videoComposition.renderSize = mutableComposition.naturalSize;

// Create the player item
AVPlayerItem* avPlayerItem =[[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:mutableComposition];
avPlayerItem.videoComposition = videoComposition;

// Create the player and return it
AVPlayer* avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];

return avPlayer;
```

}

The video does not render.

If I remove the line:

```
avPlayerItem.videoComposition = videoComposition;
```

The video renders again, since it has no custom videoComposition set on it. Several other examples I have seen appear to be doing this in the same way.

I can only assume my transform data is incorrect, Although I have tried various different numbers.

Comment: i am facing same issue. Did you find the answer for it

Answer (score 0):

Try to create immutable composition apple doesn't recommend to play mutable composition

```
AVComposition *immutableSnapshotOfMyComposition = [myMutableComposition copy];

// Create a player to inspect and play the composition.
AVPlayerItem *playerItemForSnapshottedComposition =
    [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:immutableSnapshotOfMyComposition];
```

Comment: This didn't work, I don't think this is where the problem lies. I can play the mutable composition, but only when it doesn't have the videoComposition property set on the AVPlayerItem.